# Error installing json: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: json, rubygems

Spent some time figuring this one out this:

```
gem install json
```

Resulted in this error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
  ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150611-1112-jqgxzj.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
linking shared-object json/ext/generator.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgmp
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [generator.so] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```

The important line here is "cannot find -lgmp".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solution:

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp-dev
```